# fix curl_init undefined in eclips php ide windows 7?

Tags: php, eclipse, windows-7

after many attempts i finally made curl in php 7.3.1 work with Apache server after i copy those files

```
libeay32.dll
libssh2.dll
ssleay32.dll
```

to **apache\bin** directory and copying **nghttp2.dll** too, but i find eclipse php ide easier to work on and i couldn't know how to fix curl in eclipse on my other PC since the fix above only work for Apache
the error message is curl_init undefined
and im using the latest version of eclipse php 2018-12 
extension are already activated

```
extension=C:\Php\ext\php_curl.dll
```

thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may not the right approach to fix the curl issue. If you update your php version, you may forget to copy your files over again.

The correct approach is to update the php folder path. I hope when you do this, eclipse may find the right file at the right location.

In Control Panel -> Advanced System Settings -> Environment Variables… -> Under System variables, find Path -> Add the path to the php folder.

You can look at step 4 on this page https://www.clipsify.com/tutorials/install-latest-apache-php-mysql-windows/